# How to delete an object derived from CWinThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have code like this

```
X *m = new X(); // X - class derived from CWinThread;

m->CreateThread(CRREATE_THREAD);
m->b_AutoDelete = false;
x->ResumeThread;
```

in function run I have some code, that runs in the loop.

When I try to do delete `m`, often I get an exception.

Do I need to do something before `delete`, may be `m->Suspend` or something else?

Code runs on Windows 7

Comment: I don't think you create a thread using `new`, but you'd have to call a function like [AfxBeginThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Killing a thread from outside is generally not the cleanest solution (e.g. no cleanup code on the thread runs, etc.). Usually you set a condition (like an event) and have the thread terminate by itself. Once the thread has terminated you can safely delete the C++ object wrapping it.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say, but it might crash because you kind of pull the rug out from under the feet of the thread when deleting the object.

The nice way to end a thread is to first tell it to stop. This is often done with a boolean flag that the thread function checks. It will let the thread function handle cleanup in a nice way. Once that is done, which can be checked with another boolean flag, you are then free to delete the object.